# Distributed task queue with user based scheduling/prioritization

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, task-queue

I have a number of users which can each submit an arbitrary number of tasks.
I need a task queue which will schedule the tasks to be run in such a way that one user cannot starve the processing of other users tasks by submitting many tasks during a short period of time.

So far I was trying to use the thread scheduling from `gevent` and write
the rest by myself, but it's a lot of work to do....

I found [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) which has great features, but the function I need most is missing.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Yup - celery's just for workers - check out [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)